"La nuit est sombre": why no liaison?
I am a recent beginner of French and have been studying the concept of liaison. I am doing an exercise which asks me if a liaison can occur in "La nuit est sombre." The textbook says it is NOT possible to do a liaison but I just don't know why, since it is a consonant + vowel.
Could someone help me? Thanks!

I think it sounds better without doing that liaison, personally. You could the liaison, but wouldn't sound good.

According to the Wikipedia article on French liaison, one of the impossible contexts is "between a non-pronominal noun phrase (e.g. a non-pronominal subject) and the verb". This is the case with « la nuit » (non-pronominal subject) and « est » (verb). That said, such a rule is absent from the French version of the same article. My intuition is not as well-trained as Frank's but accords with his in feeling that it's possible.

@LukeSawczak  Thank you so much you two! I've just checked in with other materials and it's true that such liaison (nominal subject + verb) is forbidden. My textbook didn't mention it :P

nuit is singular in number, which usually forbids the liaison. See https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23552/la-prononciation/liaisons/contextes-de-liaisons-interdites#:~:text=La%20liaison%20est%20interdite%20devant,produisent%20le%20son%20%5Bf%5D, which is roughly the same set of rules as in France. Note, I do not abide by the all these rules: des moulins-z-à eau and à travers-z-un amas are OK for me.

Rah ben non! la nuit z'est sombre. OEuf corse.

Liaisons are not always done, and in particular there is no liaison after a noun except from a plural s or x (both pronounced [z] when in a liaison). @LukeSawczak The rules are grouped differently but this is covered on French Wikipedia as well: no liaison “Après un nom au singulier se terminant par une consonne muette”.

Seriously now: here are less stringent rules, which is not necessarily the most helpful for you. https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/langue-francaise/regles-de-liaison

@FrançoisJurain La page proposée est loin de la réalité pour certaines liaison marquées comme obligatoires. la Terre est une planète, Ils ont agi, dans un an.

@FrançoisJurain des moulins-z-à eau and à travers-z-un amas are OK for me Huh!?

@Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Ah, true, that would cover it. It's so general I overlooked it...

Liaisons are quite volatile, some rules are not always followed.

@jlliagre Ben ouiche, c'est OK pour moi j'oblige pas que ce soit OK pour les autres. Ou c'est mon orthographe qui est bizarre? C'est mon orthographe à l'oral.

@FrançoisJurain Non, pas l'orthographe. Je n'ai jamais entendu personne dire des moulins-z-à eau ou à travers-z-un amas, ça me semble très "forçé" comme liaisons.

@jlliagre Pourtant tu dis très naturellement moulins-z-avant. Donc: moulins-z-arrière et moulins-z-à-haut. CQFD.

@FrançoisJurain Ben non justement, je ne le dis pas non plus. L'OQLF et l'Académie française (qui ne me sert pourtant pas en général de référence absolue) sont d'accord la dessus et considèrent ces liaisons comme interdites.

@Frank Not that much and when it happens, it generally only affects some "weakening" mandatory liaisons that fall in the "optional liaisons" pool. Otherwise, a large majority of mandatory liaisons and forbidden liaisons rules are followed by native French speakers. In addition, the optional liaisons rules are always strictly followed :-)

Je ne sais pas pourquoi j'ai mis une cédille à "forcé" quelques lignes plus haut mais je ne vais pas effacer ce commentaire pour que le dialogue reste compréhensible.

@jlliagre bonne idée, pas considérer l'AF comme une référence absolue. Z'ont jamais entendu parler de moulins à bas, ces caves.

@jlliagre Il y a certes des liaisons obligatoires, mais il semblerait qu'à chaque fois que le sujet est abordé sur FSE, il y a beaucoup d'avis partagés.

@Frank Je ne connais personne qui ne fasse pas la liaison dans Il faut trois ans. C'est ça, une liaison obligatoire.  La plupart sont de cet acabit. En revanche, certaines liaisons auparavant obligatoires peuvent basculer avec le temps (et donc l'usage) vers le mode optionnel. Le plus flagrant, c'est une liaison en théorie obligatoire qui n'est pourtant le plus souvent pas faite dans cent Euros. L'inverse est rarissime : une liaison interdite qui devient optionnelle. Je pencherais plutôt dans dernier cas pour de l'hypercorrection.

@FrançoisJurain La liaison est interdite après un mot pluriel (marqué d’un s) à l’intérieur de certains noms composés. [...] Il y a deux moulins à eau sur cette île.
[mulẽao] OQLF
